# "Wood board" vs "wooden board"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Intuitively, **wooden board** makes more sense, for *wooden* is an adjective meaning "made of wood," whereas *wood* is both a noun and an adjecitve. Google Ngram viewer also seems to suggest **wooden board** is the more common term:

[image]

However, I have seen **wood board** many many times. For instance: [wood boards/wood slabs](https://www.etsy.com/listing/614542975/custom-wood-slabscustom-wood-boards?ga_order=most_relevant&ga_search_type=all&ga_view_type=gallery&ga_search_query=wood%20board&ref=sr_gallery-1-2), [wood frame](https://www.etsy.com/listing/589306692/felt-letter-board-solid-oak-wood-frame?ga_order=most_relevant&ga_search_type=all&ga_view_type=gallery&ga_search_query=wood%20board&ref=sc_gallery-1-1&plkey=e3a4fbd6118cea3f41ce3c0ee56d8aef043dd75e:589306692), and [wood board AND wooden board](https://www.bestbuy.com/site/grand-star-collapsible-beer-pong-game-brown-red/5877917.p?skuId=5877917). What are the differences?

Comment: If there are no differences in the actual items I would consider it a matter of style or local convention. Could you make a case why the difference is important?

Comment: @user3169 I guess my question evolved/crystallized along this path of progression: Are both terms correct? (It appears so, since I have found attestations of both) Is it a BrE/AmE distinction? Are there semantic differences? Which should I use to describe doors, tables, flooring, etc.? If as you say it is a matter of style, then all these questions would be answered, and I would feel no longer uncertain about which term to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By some formal grammars, *wooden* is the adjective, and *wood* is the noun. Nowadays, any good descriptive reference will note, as you have, that *wood* can also be an adjective. Similar patterns exist for other materials - *golden* and *gold* being the one that comes most easily to mind. The same pattern of the noun now being recognised as an adjective as well applies in all such cases, as far as I'm aware.

Where there is some phrase that has been in continuous usage for a long time, we tend to keep using what we have always used. So while a *wooden figurine* might also be called a *wood figurine* (though the adjective *wooden* has more usage there than the adjective *wood*, according to Google ngram), a *board* made of *wood* is still a *wooden board* almost invariably.

However, *wood board* still shows usage, and has done for a long time. That's because it's a potentially valid construction even if *wood* is always a noun. There's a way of using nouns almost like adjectives, one that learners should be careful about using because it has many pitfalls. It's called using a noun *attributively*. An **attributive noun** looks like an adjective, but it isn't. It's a noun used to indicate an attribute of another noun, it is placed before the other noun and generally has a meaning equivalent to that achieved by putting the word after the other noun and putting a preposition between them.

> A **physics** degree.
>   A degree **in physics**.
>
> A **chess** game.
>   A games **of chess**.
>
> A **pancake** recipe.
>   A recipe **for pancakes**.

Thus, a "wood board" is a "board (made) of wood".